# In intern, subsequent test suites reuse browser/session

Tags: intern

In Intern, testsuites re-use the browser from the prior test suite. Although I can see the benefit of this in certain instances, I'm wondering if there is a way to set up the teardown/setup within the test suites so that the browser is closed upon completion and a new browser instance is opened when it starts. Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do where you want to restart the browser all the time? The short answer is “no”, but without understanding the reason behind this, it’s impossible to suggest what you might be able to do instead.

Comment: I'm not trying to restart the browser 'all the time', but for each testsuite.  What I'm trying to do is start specific testsuites with a clean browser, as the cleanCookies() leadfoot command does not seem to be cleaning everything up.

Comment: If `clearCookies` is not working in some environment, it is probably a bug somewhere and should be reported so it can be fixed.

Comment: @tera_incognita - did you ever get this resolved? I'm finding `clearCookies` and `clearLocalStorage` work inconsistently as well, especially in afterEach on chromedriver. adding `sleep(3000)` to the end of the change makes them fail even more instantly.

Comment: Couldn't find any config options to make it either. I think it makes sense that each functional testSuit could run in a brand new browser session. That would isolate testSuit from any changes / garbage previous tests eventually made.